# Auto-filing a formula to the last row of a column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to constantly start at cell R2 and auto-fill a formula down to the last row of column R. However, the number of rows is constantly changing so I need to write a macro that finds the last row and stops there.  My code, as it stands right now, will auto-fill column R to the end of the worksheet (not to the row where my data stops).  How do I get the auto-fill to stop at the correct row where there is no longer any data?

```
Sub InvoicePrice()

Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row

Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-4]"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R" & Lastrow)



End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  set r = range("R2")
  If r.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    lastRow = r.End(xlDown).row
   Else
    lasRow = r.row
  End If
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, I don't see a formula or any autofill command in your code

Comment: I didn't include it because you already have .autoFill  in your code and you indicated that the problem was finding lastRow. As long as your data has no gaps, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Tony, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this (avoids select/activate):

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
'Lastrow = Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
Lastrow=Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

Range("R2:R" & Lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-4]"
```

Comment: @oryan5000  If this solved your issue, please mark as accepted so this question does not linger in the open state indefinitely.